# Запись List<string> в List<List<string>>

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Есть текст, как сделать так, чтобы он записался в `List<List<string>>`,где
`List<List<string>>` - Предложение, а `List<string>` - Слова?

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: Я понимаю, как отдельно разбить сначала на list<.string>(предложения), а потом уже list<.string>(слова),можно ли сразу строку перевести в list<.list<.string>>?

Comment: Можно: `var list = text.Split('.', '!', '?').Select(sentence => sentence.Split(' ').ToList()).ToList();`

Comment: Премного благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предложение не перегружено сокращениями, то этот код сработает.
То, какие символы вырезать из исходной строки - выберите самостоятельно.

```
    // Исходная строка
    string source = @"В список отлей, завышающих цены, попал мини-отель без звезд «Люкс», расположенный на проспекте Королева, 1/9. Стоимость бронирования на период проведения чемпионата мира по футболу отеля на сайте Booking составляет 15 тысяч рублей, что превышает норматив на 514%.";

    // Убираем ненужные символы (в данном случае только запятые)
    string clearedSource = source.Replace(@",", "");

    // Делим текст на предложения
    List<string> cuttedSentence = source.Split('.').ToList();

    // Готовим место под финальный список
    List<List<string>> cuttedWords = new List<List<string>>();

    // Перебираем список предложений и каждое предложение делим на слова 
    foreach (string item in cuttedSentence)
    {
        cuttedWords.Add(item.Split(' ').ToList());
    }
```

Результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя решение с LINQ более изящное.